# How can I run my React Application in Jenkins before running Cypress?

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, cypress

In order to Run Cypress in Jenkins, I have to run my React application first.

But when Jenkins is running the React application, it throws the following error:

```
Error from chokidar (/data/node_modules/@babel/runtime/regenerator): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/data/node_modules/@babel/runtime/regenerator'
```

Error from chokidar (/data/node_modules/@emotion/unitless/dist): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/data/node_modules/@emotion/unitless/dist'
Error from chokidar (/data/node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/lib/runtime): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/data/node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/lib/runtime'
Error from chokidar (/data/node_modules/@react-pdf/layout/lib/canvas): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/data/node_modules/@react-pdf/layout/lib/canvas'
Error from chokidar (/data/node_modules/@react-pdf/layout/lib/page): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/data/node_modules/@react-pdf/layout/lib/page'
Error from chokidar (/data/node_modules/@react-pdf/layout/lib/utils): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/data/node_modules/@react-pdf/layout/lib/utils'
Error from chokidar (/data/node_modules/@react-pdf/render/lib): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/data/node_modules/@react-pdf/render/lib'
Error from chokidar (/data/node_modules/@react-pdf/render/lib/utils): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/data/node_modules/@react-pdf/render/lib/utils'
Error from chokidar (/data/node_modules/@react-pdf/stylesheet/lib): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/data/node_modules/@react-pdf/stylesheet/lib'

So it has been impossible to run the App in Jenkins.

This is the Stage in the Jenkins file that throws the error:

```
stage('Cypress') {      
  steps {        
    configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'shell-aliases', variable: 'CFG_SHELL_ALIASES')]) {  
      sh '''
      source $CFG_SHELL_ALIASES > /dev/null 2>&1
      npm run start:e2e-ci          
      '''
    }    
  }
}
```

And this is the script in the package.json file that it's running:

```
"start:e2e-ci": "REACT_APP_TEST_ENV=e2e HTTPS=true HOST=pressboxlivelocal.statsperform.com PORT=443 react-scripts start"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this env as well `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=1`  to your `start:e2e:-ci` script

Comment: It worked perfectly fine. Thanks a lot.